# How to catch svg element hover event in vue js method and how to combine native javascript hover event to vue method

Tags: d3.js, svg, vue.js, native, mousehover

I have developed vuejs + d3.js + jit library project earlier.
Nowadays, I need to attach hover function to d3.js svg element to show popup dialog of hovered element's information.
I tried many times following some stackoverflow instructions.
But all of them are not suitable for my one.
Here is my snippet code.

```
allNodes.append("circle").attr("@mouseover", "console.log('test');");
allNodes.append("circle").attr(":v-on:mouseover", "console.log('dfdfd');");
```

The above code doesn't work in anyway because the d3.js element is rendered when vue component is mounted and the vue template parser can't compile the v-on, @mouseover attribute.

But following code works fine.

```
allNodes.append("circle").attr("onmouseover", "console.log('test');");
```

So I thought that I would attach native javascript function to vue method to show popup dialog.

But I'm not sure how to config all projects structure and where to place the native function in my project.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.on("mouseover", this.vueMethod)` on your d3 selection where `this.vueMethod` is defined inside the Vue component's `methods` object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ],
    todoHovered: "hover a circle"
  },
  mounted() {
    const svg = d3.select(this.$refs.chart)
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 400)
        .attr("height", 100);
    const circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(this.todos).enter()
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 10)
        .attr("cy", (d,i) => 10 + i * 15)
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", d => d.done ? "green" : "red");
    circles.on("mouseover", this.showMessage);
    circles.on("mouseout", (e) => d3.select(e.currentTarget).attr("r", 5));
  },
  methods: {
    showMessage(e, d) {
      d3.select(e.currentTarget).attr("r", 8);
      this.todoHovered = `${d.text} is ${d.done ? 'done' : 'not done'}`;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div ref="chart">
  </div>
  <p>
    Message: {{ todoHovered }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Your answer is correct and now it is working.
Perfect.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 as of version [v6.0.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.0.0), d3 uses the event itself as first argument for [selection.on](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on). I've edited the answer to reflect this change: `showMessage(d) {...}` becomes `showMessage(e, d) {...}`.

Comment: Perfect, thats works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick question @thibautg , if I wanted to enlarge the raidus of the circle hovered, how could I do?

Comment: I've edited the answer to change the radius of the circle to 8 on mouseover (within the `showMessage` method). I've added another event to set it back to 5 on mouseout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in a few minutes you explained better than a lot of tutorials I saw online.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 thanks, you’re welcome, you made my day!